# Testing for Heteroscedasticity of Multivariate Multiple Regression

Tags: heteroscedasticity, multivariate-regression

I want to test for heteroscedasticity on a regression model with multiple dependent variables using R. I want to see if the indenpendent variable has an effect on the variance of all of the dependent variables. Not on each of the variables seperately. The dependent variables are all continuous.

Comment: Welcome to this side! To give you an answer, we need more information. How does your model look like. What do you exactly want to know? Are you looking for a method? Or for R code? (the latter we usually do not provide in CrossValidated)